# MIME PDF file attachment sent by pear is not opening

Tags: php, pdf, pear, mpdf

Here's my code for generating a PDF on-the-fly by using MPDF and sending it as attachment. I have removed unnecessary code to make things quickly understandable.

```
<?php
   require_once "Mail.php";
   require_once "Mail/mime.php";
   include 'mpdf/mpdf.php';
   $server = 'my-domain-name';

   $header = file_get_contents($server.'/pdf-header.php);
   $html = file_get_contents($server.'/pdf-data.php);
   //....Some parameters for mPDF constructor
   $mpdf = new mPDF('en-x','A4','','',$marginLeft, $marginRight, $marginTop, $marginBottom, $marginHeader, $marginFooter);
   // *** Set some properties of $mpdf object
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($html); # Write html to pdf
   $content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); // Saving pdf to attach to email 
   $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

   # Set $from, $to, $subject and parameters for SMTP Authentication
   $bodyHTML = '<p>Some HTML Body</p>';
   $bodyTXT = 'Plain Text Body for clients not supporting HTML';

   $headers = array ('From' => $from,   'To' => $to,
                     'Reply-To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);
   $smtpParams = array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port,
                        'auth' => true, 'username' => $emailID,
                        'password' => $password);
   $mime = new Mail_mime("\n");
   $mime->setTXTBody($bodyTXT);
   $mime->setHTMLBody($bodyHTML);
   $mime->addAttachment($content, 'application/pdf', 'report.pdf', false, 'base64', 'attachment');
   # Get Mime Body
   $body = $mime->get();
   # Get Mime Headers
   $mimeHeaders = $mime->headers($headers);

   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $smtpParams);
   $mail = $smtp->send($to, $mimeHeaders, $body);
?>
```

The email is sent successfully to recipient with attachment **report.pdf** having file size as expected, but the attachment does not open either in any browser not in Adobo Acrobat. The encoding of **report.pdf** is perhaps wrong.

If I replace-

```
$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S'); // Saving pdf to attach to email 
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```

with

```
$mpdf->Output();
```

The PDF is output to the browser perfectly, without any errors. That means I am messing-up with something in-

```
$mime->addAttachment($content, 'application/pdf', 'report.pdf', false, 'base64', 'attachment');
```

Similar problems have been discussed on StackOverflow but they are for picking up file from the storage and then email it. I have tried that also, but again, the PDF is corrupted.

Could any one please tell me what is wrong with my script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think, this line `$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));` is not necessary, as this is part of `Mail_mime`s work. Calling this will end up in a double encoded pdf file attachment

Comment: @Thanks Phillip. It worked. Now I got why the size seemed quite big. I thought the script was enlarging the images embedded. Just post this as Reply so that I can mark it as Reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that you double encode your pdf file. Calling `chunk_split` and `base64_encode` is part of `Mail_mime`s internal work so you don't have to do it. Calling `addAttachment` with the `'base64'` parameter only tells `Mail_mime` to encode it with *base64*, *not* that you have to do this.

To fix your code, all you have to do is to remove the following line

```
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
```